# I can't create a google developer console

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I was very surprised to see that my country is not on the Supported locations for developer & merchant registration Google developer console's list.
so is there any other alternative to create the account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a Google product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect with VPN, [Here list of VPN exts for google chrome](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20vpn%20extensions&oq=chrome%20vpn&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4129j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). In that case, google will not know your real country